# Recursions versus iteration in Angular. How to implement iteration?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I had a task to implement an iterative way and a recursive way to display category data in Frontend. The data object is an infinite category object, where each category has a subcategory. I am doing in using Angular. So far I managed to have recursion done like this:

recursive-tree component:

```
<ul *ngIf="categories" class="list-disc ml-4">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index">
      <li class="ml-4">
        {{ category.category }}
        <ng-container *ngIf="category.subcategories && category.subcategories.length > 0">
          <app-recursive-tree [categories]="category.subcategories"></app-recursive-tree>
        </ng-container>
        <button (click)="addNewEntry(category)" type="button" class="ml-4 text-blue-700 border border-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-full text-sm text-center inline-flex items-center dark:border-blue-500 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-800 dark:hover:bg-blue-500">
          <svg class="w-4 h-4" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true">
            <path d="M10.75 6.75a.75.75 0 00-1.5 0v2.5h-2.5a.75.75 0 000 1.5h2.5v2.5a.75.75 0 001.5 0v-2.5h2.5a.75.75 0 000-1.5h-2.5v-2.5z"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
```

.ts

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-recursive-tree',
  templateUrl: './recursive-tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recursive-tree.component.scss']
})
export class RecursiveTreeComponent {
  @Input() categories: any[] | undefined;

  constructor() {}

}
```

It is called from another component to draw the tree:

```
<div class="px-16">
    <div>
        <app-recursive-tree [categories]="fetchedData"></app-recursive-tree>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking of an approach on how to successfully create an Iterative version if this, but thus, I keep on making another semi-recursive version, which breaks the concept of iteration.

My object looks like:

```
export interface Category {
  category: string,
  subcateogories: Category[]
}
```

How do I make such list using iteration?

Comment: Are you sure this is not the iteration way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you understand by iterations but you can try the following with `ng-template` which is doing iterations and recursions on the same component.

```
<div>
  @for (category of categories;track category) {
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="catTemplate; context: category"></ng-container>
  }

  <ng-template #catTemplate let-subCategories="subCategories" let-category="category">
    <div>{{ category }}</div>
    @for (subcategory of subCategories;track subcategory) {
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="catTemplate; context: subcategory"></ng-container>
    }
  </ng-template>
</div>
```